# HashMap yields same hashCode for different contents

Tags: java, hash, hashmap

I have the following unit test: I create 2 different Objects of my custom type Variable. I compare their hash codes which simply returns the hash code of their names, ie String.hashCode().

Then I create 2 HashSets, each holding one variable and compare the hash codes of the sets.

In both cases the hash codes differ, as expected.

However, if I create a HashMap with the name as index and the Variable as value, the assertion fails, ie they compare the same. Why is that?

Using Oracle Java 1.8.

EDIT: I can add another guarantee: `Assert.assertNotEquals(map1, map2);` also holds.
Furthermore I think I interpret this sentence correctly:

> The hash code of a map is defined to be the sum of the hash codes of
>   each entry in the map's entrySet() view. This ensures that
>   m1.equals(m2) implies that m1.hashCode()==m2.hashCode() for any two
>   maps m1 and m2, as required by the general contract of
>   Object.hashCode().
>   Taken from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html#hashCode%28%29

```
@Test
public void test() {
    // this assertion holds
    Assert.assertNotEquals(new Variable("x").hashCode(), new Variable("y").hashCode());

    Set<Variable> set1 = new HashSet<>();
    set1.add(new Variable("x"));
    Set<Variable> set2 = new HashSet<>();
    set2.add(new Variable("y"));
    // this assertion also holds
    Assert.assertNotEquals(set1.hashCode(), set2.hashCode());

    HashMap<String, Variable> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    map1.put("x", new Variable("x"));
    HashMap<String, Variable> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map2.put("y", new Variable("y"));
    // why does this assertion fail?
    Assert.assertNotEquals(map1.hashCode(), map2.hashCode());
}
```

Here is the definition of class Variable.

```
public class Variable {
    private String name;

    public Variable(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return name.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null || !(obj instanceof Variable))
            return false;
        return name.equals(((Variable) obj).name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think the hashcode must be different in any of the cases?

Comment: I expect the 3rd assertion to hold because the first assertion holds. Same reason why the 2nd assertion also holds.

Comment: Does constructor of `Variable` you use assign the passed value to `name`?

Comment: @PM77-1, yes it does, otherwise the first assertion would fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle's implementations of both `AbstractMap.Entry` and `HashMap.Entry` define `hashCode` as:

```
public int hashCode() {
    return (key   == null ? 0 :   key.hashCode()) ^
           (value == null ? 0 : value.hashCode());
}
```

Notice the XOR operator. If the key and value both have the same hash code they will cancel out when XOR'ed, and the overall hash code for that entry will be 0.

This happens in your code because the hash code for a `Variable` is the same as the string you pass to it, and those strings are the same as the keys.

It's worth noting that different objects aren't guaranteed to have different hash codes. The only guarantee with hash codes is that equal objects will have equal hash codes. Unequal objects will usually have different hash codes if the hash function is good, but it's not a guarantee.

As it turns out, this isn't just a theoretical possibility. It's quite possible in real programs!

> The logical follow-up question is then: how can I avoid this? The HashMap is sort of a symbol table which I really like to index by name. And atm I don't have any more useful members for class Variable to include in equals() and hashCode(). Any ideas?

You could give `Variable` a different hash code from the built-in `String` implementation. An easy way to do that would be to use the stock implementation but [change the multiplier from 31](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode--) to some other prime number.

For example:

```
private int hash;

@Override public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0) {
        int len = name.length();
        h = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            h = 47*h + name.charAt(i);
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

This is a modified version of OpenJDK's `String.hashCode()` implementation. I added `h = 1` so even 1-character strings will be different.

Comment: I agree to that. But the elements differ pairwise and the hashcode of a hashmap is defined as the sum of its elements' hashcodes, isn't it? Also see my edit to the original question where I posted that map1.equals(map2) is not true.

Comment: I see. I never thought this would become an issue in the real world. I just changed the name of one variable to "asdasdfasdfasdf" and now the assertion holds as expected. Idk what to say.. I have to redesign this aspect of my program.

Comment: Ok the logical follow-up question is then: how can I avoid this? The HashMap is sort of a symbol table which I really like to index by name. And atm I don't have any more useful members for class Variable to include in equals() and hashCode(). Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will use that.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a coincidence. The `HashMap.Node` implementation (which `HashMap#hashCode()` uses)  of `hashCode()` is

```
public final int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hashCode(key) ^ Objects.hashCode(value);
}
```

Where `key` and `value` have both the same `hashCode`. For example, `key` is `"x"` and `value` is a `Variable` object created with a `name` of `"x"` (which it uses for its `hashCode`). In other words, `"x".hashCode()` and `new Variable("x").hashCode()` are equal.

Any `value ^ value` is equal to 0. So the `hashCode` of your map comes out as 0 for both maps.

Comment: You both gave the explanation at the same time. Can't accept you both, sorry.

Comment: @hooch No need for apologies. As long as you grasp the concepts. I just wanted to lay it out code wise.

Comment: Yea I was debugging through the code but too lazy too look at code not written by myself. Now that I see it, it is obvious why this happens. Thanks again.